# Moralis self-hosted server

Tags: next.js, server, ipfs, self-hosting, moralis

I have problem creating Moralis self-hosted server, I have a project I'm working on which was done by someone before, so he wrapped the entire app around Moralis provider and as at the time he created the Moralis server, he could create it on Moralis website, but not anymore.

It's a NextJs frontend which has just two components, the auth page and the NFT upload page. The app is expected to lazy-mint NFT off-chain from the NextJs frontend, store the metadata in IPFS and list on rarible, then when buyers mint to buy, they mint on-chain and that's when gas fee is paid.

Please I need guide on how to create the server or if there's advise on another way to achieve my lazy mint goal, I will greatly appreciate it. Thanks all the bosses.

I tried to create a self-hosted Moralis server so I can wrap my NextJs app around it to lazy-mint NFT to rarible for me. During the lazy-mint, I expect the metadata to be stored to IPFS for me with the help of Moralis provider. And when the NFT if finally bought, it is minted on-chain and gas fee paid.

That's the goal

Answer (score 0):

Moralis v1 which allows a user to create a server on the platform is now migrated to v2 ( API ) where a user can host the servers themselves. You can find a guide to setting up the server [here in Moralis docs.](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/self-hosted-moralis-server/self-hosted-moralis-server)

Lazymint using Rarible plugin has been discontinued. Regards that, you can use Rarible API directly or the SDK

Comment: Thanks Qudusayo for your response. Can you share with me how to make use of the API or SDK you mentioned to achieve the lazy-mint pls?

Comment: Here's a link to the lazy mint docs @Dawveed https://docs.rarible.org/reference/mint/#lazy-minting-off-chain